# Wrong month is displayed from new Date()

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have been testing moment js on jsfiddle and i am trying varius things such as displaying month,day and formatting dates but the month comes out wrong

This is the code link

https://jsfiddle.net/codebreaker87/z9d5Lusv/37/

and this is the code itself

```
var day = moment().format('dddd');
var month = moment().format('MMMM');
var date = moment().format('d');
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var nmonth = new Date().getMonth();
var gt = new Date().getTime();
var dotdate = date+'.'+nmonth+'.'+year;
var newdate = new Date();

alert(nmonth);
alert(newdate);
alert(dotdate);
alert(gt);


var fd = moment().format('dddd, MMMM d');
var fdf = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');

var nd = moment(dotdate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(5, 'days');

var frt = nd.format('dddd, MMMM d');

alert('Weekday,Month Day:: '+fd);
alert('Five Days Later:: '+nd);
alert('Five Days Later into Weekday,Month Day Format:: '+frt);
```

The code displays the current month as `10` instead of 11.

Why is it displaying the month this way?.

Comment: Months in JavaScript dates are numbered from 0 (January) to 11 (December).

Comment: @Turnip Interesting. How can i get the correct month without necessarily having to add 1?

Comment: You can create a Moment with a native Javascript Date object. moment(new Date()) for comparison.